# Why line break automatically in textview?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, line, break

I'm trying to do a custom table cell. I added a textfield in a view inside my cell and put some text in. But sometimes text inside get a line break casually. I think it was a problem of textfields so I replace with textView but the problem persist...Any ideas?

Here there is an image :

[image]

As u can see they get different line break and instead of fit the entire line casually they get a break and start a new line

Here's my code for putting text in textview:

```
var dataArray = [1 : "Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università niversità di Messina orem ipsum dolo Lorem ipsum dolo Lorem ipsum dolo Lorem ipsum dolo Lorem ipsum dolo " ,2 : "Università degli studi di Giurisprundeza di Bologna di Roma",3 :"Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università niversità ", 4 : "Università degli studi di Giurisprundeza di Bologna di Roma",5 :"Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università niversità ",6 : "Università degli studi di Giurisprundeza di Bologna di Roma",7 :"Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università di Messina Università Università di Messina Università niversità "]

var nomeArray = [1 : "asdarar awraw e awrawr awrawr hanno commentato questo elemento dsa asdasd" ,2 : "asdarar awraw e awrawr awrawr hanno commentato questo elemento dsa asdasd",3 :"asdarar awraw e awrawr awrawr hanno commentato questo elemento dsa asdasd",4 :"asdarar awraw e awrawr awrawr hanno commentato questo elemento dsa asdasd",5 : "Gianluca Materia e Davide Iuffrida hanno commentato questo elemento dsa asdasd " ,6 : "dauwdga awitawht awtiawt awitawhot awitahwot awiotha awaiaw awruhatio awitahoiwtahowtoaiwthoiawoitagiotiwagotagotawgiotaogitoasitvai",7 : "Gianluca Materia e Davide Iuffrida hanno commentato questo elemento"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell

    let yPositionHeader = cella.headerPost.frame.origin.y
    let heightHeader = cella.headerPost.frame.height

    let name = Array(nomeArray.values)[indexPath.row]
    cell.proprietario?.text = name

    cell.proprietario?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
    cell.proprietario?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0);
    cell.proprietario?.sizeToFit()

    let text = Array(dataArray.values)[indexPath.row]
    cell.miaLabel?.text = text
    cell.miaLabel?.frame.origin.y = yPositionHeader + heightHeader + 30

    cell.miaLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.miaLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
    cell.miaLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0);

    cell.miaLabel?.sizeToFit()

    let heightLabel = cell.miaLabel.frame.height
    let yPositionLabel = cell.miaLabel.frame.origin.y

    cell.azioniPost.frame.origin.y = yPositionLabel + heightLabel + 30

    let heightActionP = cella.azioniPost.frame.height
    let yPositionAzioniPost = cella.azioniPost.frame.origin.y

    cella.separatorPost.frame.origin.y = yPositionAzioniPost + altezzaAzioniPost 

    let heightSeparatorPost = cella.separatorPost.frame.height

    tabella.rowHeight = altezzaLabel + heightHeader + heightActionBar + heightSeparatorPost + 65
    return cella
}

class customCell: UITableViewCell
{
@IBOutlet weak var headerPost: UIView!
@IBOutlet var miPiace: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var Condividi: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var miaLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var azioniPost: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var proprietario: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var nomeCondividente: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var separatorPost: UIView!
}
```

EDIT : 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is what [Auto Layout](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) is for.

First of all, `UILabel` is perfect for your use case, you don't need `UITextView` or `UITextView`. `UILabel` can display multi-line text, you just have to set its `numberOfLines` property to `0` and its Line Break Mode to `Word Wrap`.

In your storyboard where you design your prototype cell (or in your cell's xib), I'm guessing you're not setting any constraints for the `UILabel`'s width. This means that Interface Builder will use the `UILabel`'s default width you have it in the storyboard, which does not always mean full screen width on all devices.

Comment: I cant using auto layout..need another solution

Comment: I see. Will you're cells auto-expand to fit their text? Or will the text scroll inside the cell?

Comment: cells auto-expand to fit text

Comment: How do you do that without Auto Layout?

Comment: As you can see in code, before I calculate label height depending on text line. Then I just calculate action tabBar "y position" and at the end i just set my rowHeight equals to labelHeight + actionBarHeight

Comment: Assuming `tabella` is your table view, I think that would give all the cells the same height. Specifically, the would all have the height of the last cell that was drawn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104813/discussion-between-paulvs-and-marco-castano).